# VC++ Headers

Tags: c++

По поводу header'ов есть несколько вопросов.  На С++ ранее не приходилось разбираться, поэтому все задачи ограничивались консолью или WinForms, будут следующие любопытные вопросы:
В одном проекте заметил такую тенденцию:
в файлах .hpp(и почему не просто .h?) указываются классы с объектами и прототипами методов, а уже в .cpp реализации методов.
Является ли такой способ(с использованием header'ов) самым оптимальным? И почему?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Чем плохо писать C++ код в .hpp файлах](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457729/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-c-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-hpp-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hpp - можно писать, как бы указывая, что заголовочник написан с использованием C++, а не C. Можно так писать. Можно просто *.h.

В принципе такой метод можно назвать самым оптимальным и даже общепринятым. Отделение определений от реализации позволяет предоставлять библиотеки в скомпилированном виде и заголовочники без самих исходных кодов. Тем самым другой программист, имеющий желание работать с библиотекой, будет иметь к ней доступ со всеми удобствами, а также это уменьшает размер распространяемого дистрибутива.

Я думаю, что другие могут привести ещё больше причин.

В общем, желательно следовать данной методике.