# Чем плохо писать C++ код в .hpp файлах

Tags: c++, библиотеки

Встречал и сам писал библиотеки одного .hpp файла. Удобно, что не нужно повторять код. Чем это может быть плохо?
Вот [пример](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/master/src/json.hpp) довольно популярной и удачной библиотеки.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под кодом? Заголовочные файлы должны иметь объявления, а не исполняемый код.

Comment: @Vlad, Вот [так](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/master/src/json.hpp)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Плохо в этом то, что вы теряете преимущества раздельной компиляции.

Во-первых, это время. Ваша функция будет компилироваться каждый раз, когда cpp-файл включает этот header. Хуже того, теперь при каждом изменении подробностей реализации придётся перекомпилировать не один cpp-файл с имплементацией, а *все*, которые включают ваш header.

Во-вторых, это увеличивающееся количество зависимостей. Если вам для декларации функции не нужны другие header'ы, а для имплементации нужны, то теперь вы вынуждены включать всё в header, и значит, все, кто его используют ваш header, тоже будут «видеть» эти другие header'ы.

К этому непосредственно примыкает и проблема номер 3: кольцевые зависимости. Допустим, у вас есть две функции в разных файлах, которые вызывают друг друга. Если в header'ах только декларации функций, то cpp-файлах можно подключить недостающий header, и функции могут легко ссылаться друг на друга. В случае, когда имплементация в header'е, такое не пройдёт из-за взаимной рекурсии включений, и вам придётся идти на уродливые трюки наподобие «точно знать, какие функции нужны другому header'у, и предварительно объявить их перед включением».

И наконец, вы теряете инкапсуляцию: любой может видеть вашу имплементацию, и это провоцирует кодировать используя знание о том, как же там всё реально устроено (что по очевидным причинам плохо).

---

Заметьте, что если ваша функция — шаблонная, то вам скорее всего таки придётся объявлять её полностью в header'е, и столкнуться со всеми вышеперечисленными проблемами.

Comment: Как я понимаю, саму библиотеку можно писать в .hpp, а компилировать в .so, а затем уже подключать?

Comment: @Linuxoid: Есил вся библиотека в .hpp, то по идее не нужно компилировать в .so.

Comment: Что вы скажете про размер скомпилированного файла? Будет ли дублироваться библиотека при компиляции каждого файла?

Comment: @kyb: Если вы пометите функции как `static`, то будет. Если не как `static`, а как `inline`, то не будет, дубликаты выкинет компоновщик.

Comment: @VladD а если не `static` и не `inline`, а `class A{ int f(){/*code*/} }`

Comment: @kyb: Это то же, что и `inline` по эффекту: код класса дублироваться не будет. Методы, описанные внутри класса, имеют неявно `inline`.

Comment: @VladD, во дела. А я им всем `inline` писал, выходит зря. Благодарю.

Comment: @kyb: Ну это если методы определены именно _внутри_ класса. Не за что :)

Comment: @VlaD, в .so компилировать только когда библиотека завершена?

Comment: @Linuxoid: Ох, я неправильно выразился. Если в библиотеке только header'ы, то в поставку библиотеки должены входить только эти header'ы, .so вовсе не нужны. Потому что объектный код сгенерируется при компиляции с подключенным header'ом в объектном модуле пользователя. (Наподобие того, как это делает boost, там тоже половина библиотек header-only).

Comment: @VladD А если код в библиотеке пишется не как классы, а как стандартная библиотека C++, то есть в namespace, но без класса?

Comment: @Linuxoid: Если в именованном namespace, то имеет значение, `static` или `inline` (и ничем не отличается от случая без namespace). Если в неименованном namespace, то это по сути ничем не отличается от `static`, т. к. компоновщик не имеет права при этом объединять функции, лежащие в разных объектных модулях.

Answer (score 7):

Реализация в заголовочных файлах не просто возможна, но и требуется в нескольких случаях. В частности, при реализации обобщённых типов, они же шаблоны (templates), а также при реализации встроенных (inline) функций.

С другой стороны, в некоторых случаях такая реализация может привести к ошибкам во время линковки, поскольку одна и та же функция окажется в разных .obj-файлах. Чтобы этого не произошло, функцию необходимо объявить статической (`static`), тогда она не будет видна из других [объектных модулей](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file). Фактически, это означает, что в каждом объектом модуле будет своя копия этой функции. Хочу обратить внимание, что в данном случае речь идёт не о статических методах класса, которые также принято обозначать ключевым словом `static`.

Резюме: это не плохо, и иногда необходимо. Главное, понимать, что и зачем вы делаете.

Answer (score 4):

Принципиально ничего плохого в этом нет. Вон boost больше чем на половину в заголовках реализован.

Минусы это увеличение времени компиляции и размера бинаря (не обязательно).

Comment: Футпринт точно не увеличивается?

Comment: @kyb что такое футпринт?

Comment: the size of executable

Comment: @kyb это да, обновил ответ

Comment: Что значит не обязательно?

Comment: @kyb То и значит что не всегда размер увеличивается, но почти всегда.

Comment: это понятно. Может знаете где прочесть прикаких таких конкретных условиях увеличивается, а при каких нет, и почему?