# Организация кода C++. Необходимоть писать имя класса в `.cpp`

Tags: c++

Мне кажется немного дикой, неудобной, и осложняющей читабельность кода необходимость указывать `имя_класса` перед каждой функцией в файле реализации класса.

файл `A.hpp`:

```
class A {
    int func(int par);
}
```

файл `A.cpp`:

```
int A::func(int par){
    return par*2/4+1;
}
```

Чтобы упаковать реализацию функций в класс можно писать [код в заголовках](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457729/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-c-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-hpp-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85) (получится аля в `Java`). Там же написано почему это не круто.

```
class A {
    int func(int par){
        return 2;
    };
}
```

Может вам извесны другие варианты записи и организации кода?

Comment: Не вижу никакого снижения читабельность от того что я напишу AES::DecryptBlock и буду точно знать о чем речь. А вот DecryptBlock непонятно какого класса (из пары десятков) точно читабельность понижает.

Comment: Да ну? Читабельность оно точно не осложняет, так как можно сразу определить, методы какого класса реализуются. В ++ нет соглашения, что в cpp реализуются строго методы из одноименного hpp, то есть можно в одном срр реализовать методы всех классов (а они могут повторяться по названиям) - поэтому, чтобы отличать их, сделано вот так и по-другому вы не напишете, только если все в заголовочном файле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это проблема/фича модели компиляции языка C++.

Дело в том, что C++ компилирует только .cpp-файлы, и из них каждый **независимо**. Это значит, что он при компиляции не знает, к чему относится данный текст, не знает контекста. Когда C++ видит методы файла, компилятор к этому моменту просмотрел сотни (это не преувеличение!) header'ов и видел предварительные описания сотен классов. Он не может просто так прикинуть, к какому из них относится данный метод.

Даже если другой метод организации компиляции можно придумать (например, использовать как-нибудь препроцессор) метод, который вы описали, является привычным и практически единственным общепринятым методом организации исходного кода в C++. Поэтому любая другая организация кода вызовет скорее всего недоумение у ваших коллег.

В других языках, например, C#, нету подобной особенности, потому что все функции определяются внутри класса. Проблем с компиляцией, как в указанном вами вопросе, не возникает, потому что для нахождения других классов не используется `#include` (который по сути является простой текстовой подстановкой), а двухпроходная и **нераздельная** компиляция: компилятор при чтении очередного .cs-файла не «забывает» то, что он видел в других файлах.

В других, например, Javascript, проблема даже шире, потому что методы <s>класса</s> объекта могут быть определены где угодно и «появиться» в объекте на любом этапе его жизненного цикла.